# bibtex does not find bibliography fields when using latexmk and outdir

Tags: bibliographies, latexmk

I compile a document with this command:

```
    latexmk -outdir=obj these.tex
```

In `these.tex`, I specify `\bibliography{../Bibliography}`. But, when `latexmk` calls `bibtex`, the `.aux` file is one folder deeper and, hence, the compiler doesn't find the file.

Indeed, if in my `.tex` file I use `\bibliography{../../Bibliography}` then everything works fine for `bibtex`, but `latexmk` fails to find the file. Using `-auxdir=obj` doesn't change anything.

What can I do ?

edit: it seems important to precise that latexmk is called via a makefile.

Comment: Why not use a place that is simply searched by default?  Using `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` gives me `~/texmf`, which means I'd put my bibliography (or a symlink even) in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib`; then `latex`, `latexmk`, etc. will all find the file regardless of all the other jiggering I might want to do with other files...

Answer (score 1):

In your project root, create a `.latexmk` file with the following contents:

```pl
$bibtex = "bibtex -include-directory=.. %O %B";
```

This tells `bibtex`, which is executed in the `obj` directory, to look for `*.bib` files in `../obj`.

Comment: BibTeX (version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017), kpathsea version 6.2.3) does not seem to support the option -include-directory.

Comment: Works for BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2020/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.2 and Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020. Version 4.70b